# Extjs MVC : Dates showing in grid but loadRecord() cannot load them into form component when clicked

Tags: date, extjs, datefield

having a bit of a problem here with what should be a pretty simple solution.
I have a Contract Model with two date fields :

> ```
>     { name: 'startDate', type: 'datetime', dateFormat: 'M d Y'},
>     { name: 'endDate', type: 'datetime', dateFormat: 'M d Y' }
> ```

In the grid these show fine E.g. "Mar 01 2013".

> ```
>             {
>                 dataIndex: 'startDate',
>                 text: 'Start',
>                 xtype: 'datecolumn',
>                 format: 'M d Y',
>                 autoWidth: true
>             },
>             {
>                 dataIndex: 'endDate',
>                 text: 'End',
>                 xtype: 'datecolumn',
>                 format: 'M d Y',
>                 autoWidth: true
>             }
> ```

When clicking on a grid item i'm loading another panel with a form component in and two datefields.

> ```
>                     {
>                         xtype: 'datefield',
>                         name: 'startDate',
>                         value: 'startDate',
>                         width: 300,
>                         disabled: true,
>                         hidden: false,
>                         fieldLabel: 'Starts'
>                     },
>                     {
>                         xtype: 'datefield',
>                         name: 'endDate',
>                         value: 'endDate',
>                         width: 300,
>                         disabled: true,
>                         hidden: false,
>                         fieldLabel: 'Ends'
>                     },
> ```

In the controller i'm simply getting the form component and passing the record to the loadRecord method. When I log the two elements from the record I get the following data.

> 2012-03-01T12:00:00
>
> 2013-03-01T12:00:00

The problem is that the form's datefields don't load the date into them to edit. It appears to be some sort of formatting or binding issue. 
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: That all looks reasonable. I'd suggest setting up a fiddle to demonstrate the issue. Also note that `datetime` isn't a valid type.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Evan. Ive altered the model to read date instead of datetime and now neither the grid or form have the date in.

Comment: What happens if you remove the format from the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model, replace `type: 'datetime'` by `type: 'date'`, and remove the `dateFormat`, which is the **expected** data format (or configure it to match your response date format). The display format is the one you've configured in your grid, and that you should configure in your date field.

This way, the response data will be parsed to a `Date` object by the model, and this date object will be correctly interpreted both by the grid and the fields.